# Password incorrect due to 2fa

Tags: 18.04, login

I have set up 2 factor authentication. I had added the following line to the end of /etc/pam.d/common-auth:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

All was working well, except for the fact that I did not get prompted for a verification code. According to [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo/) the line should be added above:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

I misread and put it beneath this line. After logging out I tried to login but now my password was no longer working. I got the error message that my password was incorrect. I am 100% sure the password is correct as I have used it many times every day. My change in the common-auth file must have corrupted the login.

Is there any way to rollback this change? I am working on a dual-boot machine and have windows installed as well. Maybe I could use the windows install to access the common-auth file and change it?

Answer (score 0):

Restart ubuntu in recovery mode. Select option 'run command line as root'. And revert changes to common-auth file.

I'm glad it helped me out, but I guess at the same time this is a huge security vulnerability as 2fa (or worse) can be disabled by anyone at any time.